# Open CL: Can one local group be executed in multiple computing units?

Tags: parallel-processing, opencl

I am running an experiment with OpenCL on CPU. There is a loop inside my kernel where all threads in a local group are synchronized in the middle of each iteration and the end of each iteration. The reason I am doing this is because it seems to me the overhead of creating cl_mem objects and enqueueing the kernel in each iteration is greater than the benefit of parallelization.

I passed the kernel a local group size which equals to the global work size, for synchronization purpose. It seems to me the kernel is executed on one CPU core instead of on all CPU cores.

Can one local group be executed in multiple computing units? If not, is there anyway to keep synchronization between multiple computing units?

Comment: What hardware are your running this on?

Comment: If you have such a long-lived kernel on a GPU, it will get killed by the OS. If you plan on having this code ever run on a GPU, you might want to rethink your strategy.

Comment: @LuboAntonov I am testing it on CPU. So this wouldn't be an issue. Does the OS wants to kill long-lived kernel because of desktop rendering? My machine has 6 GPUs attached so I presume I can safely pass the long-lived kernel to some idle GPU.

Comment: @talonmies Intel i7 Q740 + GT460M. Kernel is running on CPU with Intel SDK. I will also do another experiment on AMD FX8150 + HD5850 * 6

Comment: Yes, it will kill it on any GPU that's connected to a display.

Comment: I am wondering what you call iteration - normally, one iteration starts with input data from the host and ends with output data from the device. Within that, you can have as many loops as you want, but you would not expect communication between the host and device.

Comment: @LuboAntonov Yes, but I moved the loop to kernel instead - to save the time of transferring data.

Comment: Is it possible to have multiple cores working on the same workgroup in anyway?

Answer (score 0):

you can't synchronize different Work Groups during execution.

A compute unit is usually a group of processors which is able to communicate in order to synchronize its tasks.
For Example a Nvidia compute unit (streaming multiprocessor) has 8 streaming processors and it is only possible to synchronize the tasks runnin in this certain compute unit.

I would try to find out first, if you really have the overhead you mentioned:

How the synchronization works and how efficient it is towards simply enqueueing several kernels is dependant to the system you are using. So is a CPU is quite good at working through a lot of different kernels as you don't have to transfer them up to a GPU Memory or similar.

I would suggest you to benchmark it, OpenCL provides a powerful profiling functionality!
You have to initialise your Queue with CL_QUEUE_PROFILING_ENABLE, afterwards you can print profiling information for each event object like this for example (I am using the C++-Bindings):

```
std::vector<cl::Event> evts;
//[Create some event objects by enqueueing and executing kernels]
for (unsigned int i=0; i<evts.size(); i++) {
  evts[i].getProfilingInfo(CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_QUEUED, &param);
  printf("%u: %llu", i, param);
  evts[i].getProfilingInfo(CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_SUBMIT, &param);
  printf(" %llu", param);
  evts[i].getProfilingInfo(CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_START, &param);
  printf(" %llu", param);
  evts[i].getProfilingInfo(CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_END, &param);
  printf(" %llu\n", param);
}
```